# Is there a setting to hide full file path in Blenders title bar and show only the file name?

Tags: customization, blend-files

If I'm working with multiple Blender files it clutters my taskbar and worse, I can't tell which Blender instances contains what project. That's because it shows full file path to my open .blend file.

[image: default title bar]

How do I hide the full file path and show only the file name?

Comment: I don't think that there is any setting to change that. Only through Python perhaps, but I'm not even sure this is accessible.